# Removing Complex Duplicate data entries in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, duplicates

I'm looking to remove duplicates across several Excel spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet has 10-20 unique headers (categories) and many rows (entries). Taking one of the sheets as an example we can see that row 1 and row 200 are duplicate entries but they are only partially duplicate, row 200 may have some blank cells and there are headers such as date of entry, time of entry and unique identifier that would make this entry appear unique if looking at all headers.

Is there a way to take into consideration all of the headers and identify which entries are duplicates based on the similarity? Say row 1 and 200 have entries that are duplicate for 15/20 of the headers but unique for 5/20 but they are still duplicate entries and therefore need to be flagged/removed.

I have tried the remove duplicate function but this involves having to go through each sheet and find which headers (categories) you want to include or exclude in analysis, this would be fine if it was just one data sheet but with several where the headers differ everytime this process is too laborious.

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper column for all the sheets, that returns the count of found values. Then you can use same remove duplicates logic on all sheets.

[image]

Comment: Would this be able to take into account blanks and case sensitives across two entries that may be duplicates but due to blanks/case sensitive entries under different headers won't otherwise be picked up.

Comment: Yes, the EXACT() function can do this. Not sure about blanks. Do you want them as duplicates or not? If you provide some sample data I can help with the formula. It will be something like this

=SUM(--EXACT($A$2:$A$10&$B$2:$B$10;A2&B2))